# Download report with page update Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a situation where admin deactivates other user's account in web site, this action result in hiding of some control, updating some data in database. Deactivation also result in generation of couple of reports, one has to be save on a predefined location, other has to be downloaded. As much I know we can have only one type of response from server at a time, ie. either page update (html) or excel download, so I perform my UI and database updates on Deactivation and register a javascript function by ScriptManager RegisterStartupScript to open a modal dialog for Report Page. On load of Report Page, I generate a excel, save it on predefined location, generate other excel and send in response.

Questions

- Is there any better approach to do this?
- My Deactivation page hungs up until excel is download, which should not happen,as I am downling page through Report page.
- Some times I have to show user messages like "Save complete", "Deactivation done"  which I am doing by registring function by ScriptManager. RegisterStartupScript and then show jquery dialog. Please suggest any better approach.

Comment: A common UX I see/use for something like this would be to present the admin with the updated page, and within the updated page have a link to download the report.  Something like (using generic language): "This task was successful, click here to download a printable report."  Instead of trying to send both responses, just send an interface and let the user decide what to do.

Comment: I agree with David.  Show them a page with a link to get the report instead of forcing it to them.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with both of you, however the issue is that data required in report does not exists after deactivation of account. If I give link for download then, I either to keep that data somewhere or create report on server, which I have to cleanup later.... Please put your thoughts on this. Also if possible reply to 3rd bullet point above.